# spring security HttpSecurity

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm following the Spring Security guide from here, http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-httpsecurity

I have these set up in my `pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

In my security configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

I have

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login") 
        .permitAll();        
}
```

`HttpSecurity` has the method `formLogin`, but the other calls starting with `authorizeRequests()` return the type
   `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry` which doesn't have the method `formLogin` anymore.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the order so that the form login configuration comes first:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login") 
        .permitAll()
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated();
}
```

EDIT: changed ".and" to ".and()"

Comment: Thanks Erik. It works like that. I'm new to the java world, any idea why the spring website shows it working differently?

Comment: It's tough to see the intent of the Spring Security code here but to me it looks like there's inadvertent type erasure going on or the documentation just doesn't accurately reflect how the code is intended to work.